# PHP 7 anonymous classes

Tags: php, anonymous-class, php-7

PHP 7 has introduced a new class feature called the anonymous class which will allow us to create objects without the need to name them. Anonymous classes can be nested. What are your thoughts on memory consumption, execution time, performance issues? Are there any metrics/stats available?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anonymous classes are classes without programmer declared names, they are otherwise identical to normal classes.

Syntax allows them to be nested, just like functions:

```
function name() {
    function sub() {

    }
}
```

But just as the code above contains two globally accessible functions, the following code still contains two globally accessible classes:

```
class C {
    function method () {
        return new class{};
    }
}
```

It gives you a kind of control over where the class is *easily* accessible from, in that sense they are nested.

They are not nested in the sense that an anonymous class declared inside another class is not able to access any members of the creating class.

So that this:

```
class C {
    private $member;

    public function method() {
        return new class {
            public function method() {
                return $this->member;           
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Is not valid, because the anonymous class is not truly nested.